# Default Alarm Behaviour in Erlang

Tags: erlang

According to Erlang memsup documentation:

```
system_memory_high_watermark = float()

The threshold, as percentage of system memory, for how much system memory can be allocated before the corresponding alarm is set. Te default is 0.80 (80%)
```

What is the default behaviour when this alarm is set, in case the corresponding alarm_handler is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [alarm_handler](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/alarm_handler.html) documentation:

> The alarm handler process is a gen_event event manager process which receives alarms in the system. This process is not intended to be a complete alarm handler. It defines a place to which alarms can be sent. One simple event handler is installed in the alarm handler at start-up, but users are encouraged to write and install their own handlers.

So a default alarm handler is installed, which I think simply does nothing at all. You can write your own and attach it to the alarm handler to react to the alarms sent.

If your question is instead what happens if SASL is not started when you start os_mon, it's not possible: see [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/2252)